# How to use Principal Component Analysis (PCA) to analyze a dataset consisting of 300 samples of model temperature data that varies with altitude?

Tags: python, visualization, pca

I have 300 samples of temperature and altitude data, each with a size of 20x300. Each of these samples was generated using different characteristics. These 300 temperature profiles vary with altitude, making it challenging to visualize the data and determine which sample, out of the 300, causes the maximum change, and which sample number corresponds to the minimal deviation from the nominal temperature profile. Additionally, I need to identify samples that exhibit a similar pattern or temperature profile. I attempted to use principal component analysis to reduce the dimension to 2 components, but I am uncertain about how to interpret the data and whether I am heading in the right direction. In the sample code below, I have replicated my 300-sample data of temperature and altitude.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


"""  Create 300 Sample data for Altitude and Temperature"""
# Define the number of rows and columns
num_rows, num_columns = 20, 300

# Create an array of altitudes ranging from 100 km to 500 km
altitudes = np.linspace(100, 500, num_rows)

# Repeat the altitude values across all columns
altitude_array = np.tile(altitudes, (num_columns, 1)).T

# Parameters for generating temperature profiles
altitude_midpoint = (altitudes.min() + altitudes.max()) / 2
temperature_amplitude, temperature_frequency = 250, 0.02

# Create a sine wave to represent temperatures with altitude
temperatures = temperature_amplitude * np.sin(temperature_frequency * (altitudes - altitude_midpoint)) + 750

# Create random noise for slight temperature variations
max_variation = 50
noise = np.random.uniform(-max_variation, max_variation, (num_rows, num_columns))

# Add the noise to the temperatures to create temperature profiles
temperature_array = temperatures[:, np.newaxis] + noise


""" Principal Component Analysis"""

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

run_number = np.arange(1, 301).reshape(300, 1)

pca = PCA(2)  
principal_components = pca.fit_transform(temperature_array.T)
print(temperature_array.shape)
print(principal_components.shape)


# Create a figure with two subplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(12, 5))

# First subplot
# Plot temperature vs. altitude for all 300 profiles
for i in range(num_columns):
    sc1 = axs[0].plot(temperature_array[:, i], altitude_array[:, i], label=f'Profile {i+1}', alpha=0.8)

# Plot the nominal temperature profile with marked lines
nominal_temperature = temperature_amplitude * np.sin(temperature_frequency * (altitudes - altitude_midpoint)) + 750
axs[0].plot(nominal_temperature, altitudes, 'k', linewidth=2, label='Nominal Profile', linestyle='--')

# Set plot labels and title
axs[0].set_ylabel('Altitude (km)')
axs[0].set_xlabel('Temperature (K)')
axs[0].set_title('Temperature vs. Altitude Profiles')

# Second subplot
sc2 = axs[1].scatter(principal_components[:, 0], principal_components[:, 1],
                     c=run_number.T, edgecolor='none', alpha=0.5,
                     cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('Accent'))
axs[1].set_xlabel('component 1')
axs[1].set_ylabel('component 2')
fig.colorbar(sc2, ax=axs[1])

# Third subplot
sc3 = axs[2].plot(np.cumsum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_))
axs[2].set_xlabel('number of components')
axs[2].set_ylabel('cumulative explained variance')


plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: sample plots]

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely on the right track. Based on your objectives, using PCA as a starting point to better understand and analyze your data seems like a sound strategy.

From reviewing your code and the resulting figures, it appears you've applied dimensionality reduction across the *altitude* dimension. However, you likely meant to perform PCA across the *profile* dimension instead. Essentially, you're aiming to understand your profiles by identifying a few "latent" *profiles* that capture the bulk of the variance observed across the altitude dimension. In the language of *sklearn*, the **altitude is your sample dimension** and your **temperature profiles are the feature dimension**.

The key piece that needs adjustment is this line:

```py
principal_components = pca.fit_transform(temperature_array)  # <-- no transpose!
```

BTW: You actually can see that you used the "wrong" dimension from looking at the principal component scores and the explained variance ratio.

- **PC scores**: Correct dimensionality will show your average temperature profile as the first principal component, indicating a meaningful reduction. Conversely, your current formulation primarily reveals noise.
- **Explained variance ratio**: With the dimensions properly aligned, the first component should account for nearly all the variance, effectively summarizing the data. Subsequent components would only contribute minimal additional variance, essentially representing noise. Your current setup, however, suggests that all modes are dominated by noise.